# How can I prevent duplicate usernames, given that they are case sensitive by default?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-authentication

By default, Django usernames are case sensitive. Apparently, this is something that [won't be fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2273).

This can be a good feature, particularly if other characters aren't going to be allowed. For example, my own username might look better as StringsOnFire. However, giving users a unique URL from their username is not possible by default.

I would like to:

- Allow a mix of upper and lower case letters in a username
- Ignore casing only when validating that new usernames are unique
- Leave the `contrib.auth` user models untouched

What are the possible solutions? Which method is best?

Comment: Have you noticed that your SO profile link is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/2245934/stringsonfire`? You can store both what the user actually types (`'StringsOnFire'`) and the lower-cased version (`'stringsonfire'`) and check against *the latter* when validating that a new account is new.

Comment: Yes, but a unique URL from a username would be `http://stackoverflow.com/users/stringsonfire`. SO uses the username as a slug, and uses the unique user number or ID to find the profile. I would like users to see domain.com/username, and use that username to find the user's details.

Comment: Then I suppose my second suggestion will work best for you.

Comment: Isn't there a way to compare the input username and existing usernames as lower case, just during validation, rather than storing the data twice?

Comment: Why remove Django from the title? I expect there are Django-specific ways of solving this, no?

Comment: We generally don't include *"tags"* in titles unless it's actually part of the sentence; the [tag:django] tag itself is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`CustomUserManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager.create_user) and in the `create_user()` method, do a case insensitive check to see if the username is already present with [`iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-iexact)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution:

```
def clean_username(self):
    kwargs = {
        '{0}__{1}'.format(UsernameField(), 'iexact'): self.cleaned_data['username'],
    }
    if User.objects.filter(**kwargs):
        raise ValidationError(_('A user with that username already exists.'), code='invalid')
    return self.cleaned_data['username']
```

*UsernameField() is from django-registration-redux.*

If there are any problems with this approach, please say!

Answer (score 0):

I do it with RegistrationFormCaseInsensitive form from django_registration (https://pypi.org/project/django-registration/)

After install:

In admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Create forms.py with:

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationFormCaseInsensitive
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserForm(RegistrationFormCaseInsensitive):
    class Meta(RegistrationFormCaseInsensitive.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
```

in urls.py add one of this imports:
for one step registration:

```
from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView
```

or for registration with mail link:

```
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView
```

and then add the path:

```
path("accounts/register/",
     RegistrationView.as_view(
         form_class=CustomUserForm,
         success_url="/"
     ), name="django_registration_register"),
```